ASE apply strains to entire cell
I'm just starting out with ASE, and wanted to write a program to calculate the Poisson's ratio for a material, by applying strains to a unit cell. I have written the following code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ase.build import bulk
import Morse
from ase.units import GPa

# Create the copper crystal
cu = bulk("Cu", "fcc", a=2.2614, cubic=True)
calc = Morse.MorsePotential()
cu.set_calculator(calc)

# Define a range of normal strains
normal_strains = np.linspace(-0.02, 0.02, 10)  # 10 normal strains from -2% to +2%

# Initialize lists to store results
axial_strains = []
transverse_strains = []

# Apply normal strain and calculate the resulting transverse strains
for normal_strain in normal_strains:
    strained_cu = cu.copy()
    cell = strained_cu.get_cell()
    original_cell = cell.copy()  # Save the original cell for reference
    cell[0, 0] *= (1 + normal_strain)  # Apply normal strain in the X direction
    strained_cu.set_cell(cell, scale_atoms=True)
    strained_cu.set_calculator(calc)
    
    # Calculate the resulting strains in the Y and Z directions
    new_cell = strained_cu.get_cell()
    print(f"new cell: {new_cell}")
    print(original_cell)
    transverse_strain_y = (new_cell[1, 1] - original_cell[1, 1]) / original_cell[1, 1]
    transverse_strain_z = (new_cell[2, 2] - original_cell[2, 2]) / original_cell[2, 2]

however, this code applies strain in the x direction, but the Y and Z directions remain unchanged. How could I apply a strain to X to get a strain in the Y and Z directions, to be able to calculate Poisson's Ratio?
As reference, here's a debug print of old and new unit cells:
new cell: Cell([2.2161720000000003, 2.2614, 2.2614])
original cell: Cell([2.2614, 2.2614, 2.2614])
new cell: Cell([2.2262226666666667, 2.2614, 2.2614])
original cell: Cell([2.2614, 2.2614, 2.2614])
new cell: Cell([2.2362733333333336, 2.2614, 2.2614])
original cell: Cell([2.2614, 2.2614, 2.2614])
new cell: Cell([2.246324, 2.2614, 2.2614])
original cell: Cell([2.2614, 2.2614, 2.2614])
new cell: Cell([2.256374666666667, 2.2614, 2.2614])
original cell: Cell([2.2614, 2.2614, 2.2614])
new cell: Cell([2.2664253333333333, 2.2614, 2.2614])
original cell: Cell([2.2614, 2.2614, 2.2614])
new cell: Cell([2.2764759999999997, 2.2614, 2.2614])
original cell: Cell([2.2614, 2.2614, 2.2614])
new cell: Cell([2.2865266666666666, 2.2614, 2.2614])
original cell: Cell([2.2614, 2.2614, 2.2614])
new cell: Cell([2.2965773333333335, 2.2614, 2.2614])
original cell: Cell([2.2614, 2.2614, 2.2614])
new cell: Cell([2.306628, 2.2614, 2.2614])
original cell: Cell([2.2614, 2.2614, 2.2614])

Thanks!

If you wish the cell to "strain itself" you should perform a calculation in which this is possible. That is, perform a cell relaxation.
The machinery to do this is available in ASE, and entails attaching a filter to the cell and performing a geometry optimization. Since you do not want to touch the applied strain, this optimization has to be constrained in some way.
box = ExpCellFilter(new_cell, mask=[0,1,1,0,0,0])
dyn = BFGS(box)
dyn.run(fmax=0.01)

The mask keyword allows you the specify which directions are allowed to relax (y and z in this case). Note that prior to this, the cell has to be fully relaxed (zero strain in all directions) since otherwise you're applying two kinds of strain (the one you wish to study and the once arising from non-ideal lattice parameters).
